# Evenly split items as screen shrinks

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a menu that can have a variable number of items. As the screen width decreases, I would like for half the menu to drop to a second row. Ideally, I could have this happen again as the screen gets even smaller and have four rows but honestly two rows will probably be enough before I can just hide it and show the hamburger icon.

Currently, it just goes to being a vertical menu when the screen gets too small.

I'm not sure if what I'm asking is a common, easy thing or if it would actually require some custom coding to accomplish. So I'm open to alternative solutions as well. For example, one idea I have is possibly to wrap every three menu items in a div such that it may not produce the even splits I'd like, but would move 3 items down at a time which isn't my first choice but I think would be a workable compromise.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the menu items to wrap to a second (or more) rows by limiting the width of the navbar `ul` and adding `flex-wrap.`

You won’t be able to get the menu items to wrap equally (the items will go to the end of the space and then wrap), but it that’s important to you, you could adjust the width of the navbar `ul` using custom media queries to get the menu items to move more equally.

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-light">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto w-75 flex-wrap">
            <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Lorem ipsum</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">dolor sit</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">amet consectetur</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">adipisicing elit</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Temporibus</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">corporis suscipit</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">unde quidem adipisci</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">ipsa rem</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">aliquam error</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">quas nesciunt</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">voluptatibus</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">quasi veniam illum</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">tempora quam</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">cupiditate</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">officia</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">fuga</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">esse</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```