# Navbar Bootstrap4 multiples lines

Tags: asp.net, bootstrap-4, navbar

How do I configure the Bootstrap4 navbar to resize to 2 lines or more when there is an excess of components?

This navbar is automatically generated via the system displaying the product groups.

```
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-light" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div id="navbarCollapse" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
            <ul class="navbar-nav" runat="server" id="navbar">
                <li class="nav nav-item dropdown"><a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" runat="server" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" href="#">INICIO</a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown" runat="server" id="div_inicio_dropdown">
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="Home.aspx">HOME</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" id="cmd_menu_mesas" runat="server" href="ComandaMesa.aspx">MESAS</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="ComandaMesaAberta.aspx?mes=0">COMANDAS ABERTA</a>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

[image]

Comment: wrong approaches - put your one line menu items, on a drop down menu

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/

Comment: You can get the menu items to wrap to a second (or more) rows by limiting the width of the navbar ul and adding flex-wrap. See this answer for a solution to the same need: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67133165/1011984

Comment: @RichDeBourke. Exactly I needed.
Thanks so much for the help.